# Apache Jena on IntelliJ - Problem with configuration

Tags: java, log4j, jena

I have a problem with configuration of Apache jena on IntelliJ. This is my main class where I have tried to configure apache Jena. Basically it gives BasicConfigurator in red, so it clearly not exist in the library; I have downloaded the last version of apache-jena. Moreover all the other import works, so I cannot understand why  'import org.apache.logging.log4j.BasicConfigurator;' doesn't.

Has anyone the same issue? How can I fix it?

Here the code:

```
package com;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.NullAppender;
import java.lang.Object;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger= (Logger) LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // setUp jena configuration
        org.apache.logging.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure(new NullAppender());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're not using a build tool like Maven or Gradle to handle your dependencies, then you need to add the jar-file manually to your class path. I would recommend you to start using a build tool though.

Comment: Find out that BasicConfiguration is not part of package that I have downloaded. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: `BasicConfigurator` is from Log4j1. Jena uses Log4j2 and this is in the download. To set up logging, call `LogCtl.setLog4j2()`. or add a class static: `static { LogCtl.setLog4j2() ; }`